# what is metadata_host in azuread.Provider in pulumi

Tags: pulumi

Trying to set up a provider in pulumi for Azure AAD and found this poorly documented paramter `metadata_host` (https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azuread/api-docs/provider/#metadata_host_python).
Anyone knows how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "default", you can either set it to an empty string, or `management.azure.com`.

There's an issue in the `pulumi-azuread` provider to make this better in the future: https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azuread/issues/362